# Integrating Face Recognition System Using Opencv In Browser

Tags: python, django, opencv, face-recognition

I wanted to integrate a facial recognition inside my website i.e inside a browser using OpenCV Python and I was wondering how can that be achieved?﻿

I have surfed the internet and solutions I got are through using tensorflow.js but I don't know how to use it. So I figured, there could be an easier way instead of using tenorflow.js.

Using OpenCV Python, I know how to identify a face via webcam run by the OpenCV. But I want the frame to appear inside my broswer(website).

What I want to achieve is a face recognition that works inside my website i.e browser.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV has some parts of it that have been translated to javascript. See the [OpenCV JS Tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d10/tutorial_js_root.html) for the full docs. The [object detection](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d73/tutorial_js_table_of_contents_objdetect.html) section has some entries regarding the face detection.

[js-objectdetect](https://github.com/mtschirs/js-objectdetect/) and [HAAR.js](https://github.com/foo123/HAAR.js) also implement some widely used algorithms.

Comment: I've already written code for face recognition with OpenCV python, so my question is how do I merge them together with OpenCV,js or does that mean I have to start all over again?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. If you want to run the algorithm on the server, you will have to find a way to use JS to stream the video to the server, do the opencv thing in python there, and then feed the data back to the user. This seems a bit too expensive, so unless you have a good reason to do this, I would suggest you go with an approach that runs inside the browser (i.e. using JS).